# What do you call that tiny sound you make with the nose to indicate that you're listening?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not very sure if *grunt* is the right word. I think a grunt is louder and comes mainly from the throat. I'm looking for a word that expresses a softer noise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please make this an answer.

Comment: Please record this noise and post a link to the resulting sound file. Otherwise my answer would only be a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible word for this might be 'hum'.

Hum

> to say with closed lips, without articulating words.

Tom agreed with him and gave a hum, "Mm.".

Answer (score 4):

Delightful question. A nasal pragmatic (subset backchannelling!) marker! Is this the *ah-hah*? (rising intonation, if that's the right word for hums). Or the mono'syllabic' *Hmm.*

Other 'hums' include

the equivalent of 'What!?' (*hmMMM?*).

The 'No!' (*uh-huh*; falling intonation).

The eureka *Aah*.

The discovery of a sinister plot by the kids (*A-hah*)'

The disgusted *eugh*.

The 'haven't a clue' (single high note) (possibly rendered *Huh?*.)

If bib wants a nasal dictionary, he can write his own.

Comment: [Here's a visual nasal dictionary of grunt tonality.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H82f-OKKUj8)

Comment: It makes you realise that pigs really might be super-intelligent. I missed the exasperated ... dismissive cline (Hah!?)

Answer (score 1):

The act of [sniffing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sniff) might suggest what you are describing:

> - To inhale a short, audible breath through the nose, as in smelling something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a word for it - you'd just imitate the noise.

(I'm assuming here...)

The sound you're referring to is usually spelled "Mm" or "Mm-hmm" (the latter to differentiate it from the sound you make when something smells yummy)

"I don't know if he was listening, or not - he just *'Mm-hmm'd'* at me - so, I'll take it as a 'yes'." (US)